# Displaying multiple parts of an expression in a single output

Tags: output-formatting

I have the following code:

```
names = {"Gly", "Ala", "Ser", "Pro",  "Val", "Thr", "Cys", "Leu/Ile", 
   "Asn", "Asp/isoAsp", "Gln", "Lys", "Glu", "Met", "His", "Phe", 
   "Arg", "Tyr", "Trp", "4-hydroxyPro", "5-hydroxyLys", 
   "6-N-methylLys", "\[Gamma]-carboxyGlu", "selenoCys", "phosphoSer", 
   "phosphoThr", "phosphoTyr", "\[Sigma]-N-methylArg", 
   "6-N-acetylLys", "Glu \[Gamma]-methyl ester", "Ornithine", 
   "Citrulline", "3-methylHis", "N,N,N-trimethylLys", "N-acetylAla", 
   "3-sulfinoAla", "N-acetylCys", "pyroGlu", "N-acetylGly", 
   "Met sulfoxide", "Met sulfone", "N-acetylSer", "N-acetylThr", 
   "Kynurenine", "Tyr O-sulfate"};
list = {57.0215, 71.0371, 87.0320, 97.0528, 99.0684, 101.0477, 
   103.0092, 113.0841, 114.0429, 115.0269, 128.0586, 128.0950, 
   129.0426, 131.0405, 137.0589, 147.0684, 156.1011, 163.0633, 
   186.0793, 113.048, 144.089, 142.110, 173.032, 150.954, 166.998, 
   181.014, 243.029, 170.116, 170.105, 143.058, 114.079, 157.085, 
   151.074, 170.141, 113.047, 134.999, 145.019, 111.032, 99.032, 
   147.035, 163.030, 129.042, 143.058, 190.047, 243.020};
subsets = 
 DeleteDuplicates@
  Select[Subsets[list, {3}], 344.160 <= Total[#] <= 344.163 &]
```

which produces the expression:

{{71.0371, 103.009, 170.116}}

To display the parts of this expression as their names, I'm using:

```
seqNam = names[[Position[list, subsets[[1]][[1]]] [[1]][[1]]]]
seqNam = names[[Position[list, subsets[[1]][[2]]] [[1]][[1]]]] 
seqNam = names[[Position[list, subsets[[1]][[3]]] [[1]][[1]]]]
```

but I would like do display all parts as one line of output, and I don't know how. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `names[[Position[list, #][[1, 1]]]] & /@ subsets[[1]]`

Answer (score 2):

Another method

```
Pick[names, Thread[list == #]] & /@ subsets[[1]] // Flatten
```

> {"Ala", "Cys", "σ-N-methylArg"}

Answer (score 1):

Given `names` and `list` as you have defined them. I would add `Flatten` your definition of `subsets` to simplify retrieval. Like so:

```
subsets =
 DeleteDuplicates @
   Select[Subsets[list, {3}], 344.160 <= Total[#] <= 344.163 &] // Flatten
```

> `{71.0371, 103.009, 170.116}`

Also, because `Position` is designed to used with [`Extract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html), one way to get the names is:

```
Extract[names, Position[list, #]] & /@ subsets // Flatten
```

> `{"Ala", "Cys", "σ-N-methylArg"}`

However, if you are going to doing this kind of lookup a lot, I reccomend making a dictionary (an [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html)) and  doing the lookup with the buit-in function [`Lookup`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html), which gives very readable code.

```
dictionary = AssociationThread[list, names];
Lookup[dictionary, subsets]
```

> `{"Ala", "Cys", "σ-N-methylArg"}`

Answer (score 1):

You may make use of [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) with the `names` as keys and `list` as values.

```
rules = Thread[names -> list];
Select[Association @@@ Subsets[rules, {3}], 344.160 <= Total[#] <= 344.163 &]
```

> ```
> {<|"Ala" -> 71.0371, "Cys" -> 103.009, "σ-N-methylArg" -> 170.116|>}
> ```

```
Select[Association @@@ Subsets[rules, {2}], 103.4 <= Total[#] <= 144.8 &]
```

> ```
> {<|"Gly" -> 57.0215, "Ala" -> 71.0371|>, <|"Gly" -> 57.0215, "Ser" -> 87.032|>}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pick[names, list, Alternatives @@ subsets[[1]]]
```

> ```
>  {"Ala", "Cys", "σ-N-methylArg"}
> ```